# Interfaces or only classes when testing in Java?

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, mockito

What's the tendency with Java Tests? It's keep using interfaces how it's done with JMock or only classes how it's done with Mockito? Or both are ok? I really like Mockito because I feel it easier for write and understand test but sometimes I don't understand why with JMock you have to create an interface just with the purpose to use it on tests, What's your recommendation?

Comment: This is a very broad question, and it's not clear why there are only two mutually-exclusive choices here or which property (clarity, flexibility, ease of writing, etc) you're optimizing for. Can you add more details?

Comment: @JeffBowman thanks for your recommendation, I updated the question, I used only two mutually-exclusive choices because I'm writing tests with both and I'd like not use Jmock anymore and only use Mockito, as I added, sometimes I don't understand the reason to create an interface just to use it later on tests, maybe I'm still rookie on this topic.

Comment: @psantamaria Test code is as important as running code. A professional sw project has about the same number of lines in test code as in main code. So test code is part of the software. It forms an unit. The runtime source code without the test code is of less worth. And test should not be implemented afterwards, instead it should be developped in parallel.

Comment: @AlexWien thanks for your comment, I know and I understand the importance of tests, actually, in my current project we have the rule that nothing is finished until it has test (UT, IT, etc), also we try to apply TDD whenever it's possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use interfaces, for new self written code supporting a test driven design.

Use Mockito for code that was not desiged to be unit tested, or which has an extreme integrational character. Like code that starts up the whole system.
If such a code was not deigned to be unit tested, then it is very difficult to introduce that afterwards. In that case mockito is the simpler task.

Comment: why do you need interface though, if you can mock the class. If an interface is created for the sole purpose of unit test, that seems wrong.

Comment: Agreed. I tend to write many, many interfaces but I wouldn't do so just for testing. If testing is the only reason for an interface, that has a certain smell to it.

Comment: @bayou.io To make a code testable nothing can be wrong. One of the main aspect of software that it is testable.It's a very old (>20 years) design paradigma coming from automotive SW development that code should not contain any test support / code. This paradigma is outdated.

Comment: the code is testable by mocking the classes; we don't need interface for that. 20 years ago we didn't have tools like Mockito or PowerMock

Comment: If yau don't design for testability even mockito can not help you. If  there is no method for a specific calculation task (later to be tested isolated) then there is nothing to mock. The mocking tools fools many developer, to beleive they can start writing test code after the main code is done. This leads to test code that touch classes, instead to test them. There are many issues with incompabilities between JUnit and Mocking tools.